# IPC 'server start' gets RuntimeError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ipc

I recently started building a Dashboard for my Discord Bot and connected it to my bot via [discord.py-ipc](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py-ipc/), but upon starting, I get a *RuntimeError* stating that the coroutine `Server.start()` was never awaited. This is triggered by my code to run the ipc:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.ipc.start()
    bot.run('TOKEN')
```

However, `bot.ipc.start()` can't be awaited since it isn't an async function.
I looked through the [discord.py-ipc documentation](https://discordpy-ipc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/examples/) multiple times and didn't find any errors in comparison to the example file on the docs.
I believe it could be an error in the code of the bot Class:

```
class TapBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ipc = ipc.Server(self, secret_key="secretKey")
        
    async def on_ipc_read(self):
        print("IPC is ready")
    async def on_ipc_error(self, endpoint, error):
        print(endpoint, "raised", error)
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("ready") 
             
bot = TapBot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)
```

I also tried the fix to a `RuntimeError` there was on the discord.py-ipc page (Link is the same as above, if you want to check it), which resulted in the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!